# Place to set up an open source project and find contributors

Tags: startup

I have some ideas on a project which I would like to offer for open source development. I can describe these on the level of user stories and would like to set up a team of contributors to take it further to UI design and finally first phase of development.

I know there are GitHub and similar places, but it seems like they expect someone to bring the project on the stage where there are a few lines of code. This is not my case. I am looking for contribution on the analytic and requirement collection phase.

Where do I start?

Comment: This might be more on-topic over at http://startups.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the answer to your question is "sozialize"! You have a user story, that's great. Start to promote your ideas on Facebook, on Twitter, your blog, user communities and show your passion. Spread your word to get followers and finally coders as well.

The rest depends on the size of your project in mind and how interesting your ideas are for others. Forget it, if you're just looking for someone who does free coding for you. It wont work. Don't waste your time and better learn to code yourself.

Even you might find some better code sharing platforms to promote your open source ideas you wont succeed because nobody cares. I could name you Code-Plex, SourceForge and other alternatives to startup an open source project, but they are all just tools for sharing code each with its own advantages and disadvantages, but none of them helps to get you started.

But if you are serious, rather than starting a new project I would start looking what others are doing with similar projects and get involved. You don't have to be a developer! Contribute as a user, report bugs, help others, promote your ideas, contribute to documentation, read the mailing lists, meet the developers, watch their chat in IRC and don't fear to ask questions yourself.

There will always be some people and developers thinking like you. Talk to them and team-up with them. Define clear goals and be prepared to be a strong leader with excellent communication skills.

Creating a successful open source project is not something done over night, it's a long-term process.

To become successful you have to establish an organization and you must be prepared to let it go it's own way with or without your original ideas.

Think about it and go for it!

Comment: I am a former developer, project manager and freelance dev. manager. In all the previous roles the projects were driven by money from a customer, I think I am good at that. But the project which I am thinking of is for community and I don't think I can find an investor here so the open source idea is my current bet. I am surprised there are no sites which assist people in connecting ideas the same way as the coders connect code...